# How to delete the part of the text that is repeated from excel cell - is there a formula?

Tags: excel-formula, substitution, repeat

I'm not an advanced user, but I will try to be specific.
Does anyone know how to do following: I have some phrase in cell A1. I have the same phrase in cell B1, but B1 may contain and some other phrases. My preferred result in cell C1 is text from B1 without that **specific phrase** from cell A1 (**as many times as it appears** in A1 and **no matter where it appears** in A1 ). And so on for A2, B2, C2, A3, B2, C3...

Let me explain in an example: I want to remove only phrase "Msg from" from B1 (as many times as "Msg from" appears in A1 and no matter where "Msg from" appears in A1)

A1 Smth else, Msg from, Msg from  ---> there're two "Msg from"

B1 Msg from, Msg from, Msg from, Smth else, Smth else---> there're three "Msg from"

C1 (preferred result) Msg from, Smth else, Smth else ---> I want just one "Msg from" (3 "Msg from" - 2 "Msg from" = 1 "Msg from")

A2 Msg from, Smth else, Smth else

B2 Smth else, Smth else, Msg from, Smth else

C2 (preferred result) Smth else, Smth else, Smth else

A3 Smth else, Msg from, Smth else, Msg from

B3 Smth else, Smth else, Msg from, Msg from, Smth else, Msg from

C3 (preferred result) Smth else, Smth else, Smth else, Msg from

...

Okay, if anyone has any idea, or needs more explanation, please answer, I have over 10,000 rows to arrange like this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you know which if the phrases in A1 to use and in which order in B1 to delete them?  In one you leave the first instance and in another the last.

Comment: Exactly! It does not matter in which order. The point is to get result without that specific phrase, as many times as it appears in A1. If B1 has three times that phrase repeated, and A1 has one time, then result should be B1 cell with one phrase "Msg from" less. But sometimes it is the first, last or in the middle. And other phrases from the cell A are not relevant.

Comment: do you know the specific phrase ("Msg from") before hand? is it always "Msg from" or you define it or what?

Comment: is there a maximum number of times that "msg from" can occur

Comment: would deleting MSG FROM entirely from B1 and then adding MSG FROM the number of times required at the end or start be acceptable?

Comment: Yes, I know the specific phrase. Like in an example "Msg from" it is unique value. Smth else can be anything, very different phrases..

Comment: Forward Ed - no! Because, I don't know how many times is required. Actually, it is the result that I need. The result that I need is difference between the number of times it appears in B1 and A1

Comment: oh that is easier!  had to make that calculation to determine the number of times to add it back in!

Comment: "msg from" can occur two or three times.

Comment: Do you need the calculation only or also the column with the actual string processed?

Comment: The column with the actual string processed. The thing is, Columns are months in some Report. It happened, and can not be undone, that month in Column B contains a certain data from the previous month (Column A), as well as the same data from that month, and now the Report is unrealistic. Because it has around 10000 rows, I was hoping that there is a formula so a specific phrase, which differ from all others and are identical in both columns, can be removed by comparing or similar.. Otherwise, I have to go row by row and remove this phrase from month B as many times as it appears in a month A.

Comment: @ScottCraner did you hit your quota for the day on/before this one?  Throwing you lackeys a bone?

Comment: @ForwardEd family get together and wedding. You and Jeeped had it under control today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B2,D2,"")&REPT(", "&D2,(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,D2,"")))/LEN(D2)-(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,D2,"")))/LEN(D2))
```

With the assumption that you can place your target text or MSG FROM in D2, or place directly in formula replacing D2. Copy down as required.

This will replace all the target text in B2 with nothing or "".  It will then add on the target text to the end of the message the required number of instances. which is count in column B - the count in column A.

The following formula counts the number of times the target text occurs in B2:

```
(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,D2,"")))/LEN(D2)
```

And to count the number of times the target text occurs in A2 we tweak the formula and get:

```
(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,D2,"")))/LEN(D2)
```

Based on your comments, the answer to the difference to the number of times it appears in columns A and B is the difference between the two previous formulas:

```
=(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,D2,"")))/LEN(D2)-(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,D2,"")))/LEN(D2)
```

if the result is negative it means it appears in A more than it appears in B.  A result of 0 means an equal number of appearances.

Proof of concept:

[image: proof of concept]

Comment: Column f has the count.  I was missing an opening ( in front of LEN function.  I fixed that.  Does what is happening in the image work for you? On a side note there are [two excellent table to ASCII editor in this link](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6700/is-there-a-webapp-to-create-ascii-art-tables/8232#8232?newreg=d6a1958e2e264d7189c77f33c6e80404) for helping post data into a questions.  The first one is great for copying and pasting from excel, the second is good for generating your own from scratch.  Can be a little easier to read than cell A1 description cell A2 description.

Comment: the formula is referring to row two results. and if I look at your C2 results there is no "Msg from".  May be a case of you have the formula off by a row and looking at the wrong results.  Make sure the numbers in the formula are the same as the row number the formula is in.  I reread my post and I had one B1 reference in a description.  I replaced that with B2 as it should have read.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a LOT! You are a genius!

Comment: And thanks for the tip, I'll keep that in mind for future posts ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with find and replace but in replace section don't write anything after finding all and press replace it will delete the same part of text that repeated in whole cells